# Internal Server Error Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

I've uploaded wordpress file in my panel. But I can't configure my wordpress site with database. When i browse my site as **************.us**, it shows **500 Internal Server Error error**. So, i've deleted all uploaded files and uploaded again. But i'm facing this problem again and again.
So, i'm seeking a better solution.

Comment: Try to enable PHP's debug flags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Check all the file permissions. 644 for files and 755 for folders

Comment: http://**********.us/cgi-bin/  this also  shows <b>INTERNAL ERROR</b>

Answer (score 0):

Check files and folder permissions as follows:

public_html folder should have 750 and chown it to cpaneluser:nobody
files inside public_html/ should have 644 permissions
folders inside public_html/ should have 755 permissions

Check if there is any .htaccess file inside your public_html folder. If there are any rules inside that file those could lead to the error

If you do not need the rules or the file, you can just delete it.

Answer (score -2):

to increase php post limit
128M And also upgrade your current version.
for support click he[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com)re

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.